# Calling a tracking PHP script within a download PHP script

Tags: php, html, analytics, tracking, execute

So I'm trying to develop a site for personal use and so far I've got a Google Analytic account and some basic infrastructure. I would like to have a download function for which I have a script which I managed to acquire from another question on this site, however I can't seem to find an efficient way to call the tracking.php within the download script. I have been unsuccessful in the sense that GA will pick up the request but the file will be downloaded in random gibberish on a separate tab.

Here is the download script I am using at the moment:

```
    <?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/store/files/";
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['id'];


if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;


    }

}

fclose ($fd);
exit;
?>
```

The Google Analytics tracking code (tracking.php) is in another separate PHP file within the same directory. I have attempted using the exec and include functions but to no avail.

Any ideas on how I may correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably go around this with some [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

Basically, instead of trying to track within the download, track that the user clicked the download link:

```
<a href="toyourdownloadscript.php" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Download', 'The name of your download']);">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I still can't get the events to populate under GA. The tracking snippet has been place the </head> tag and I have a few simple links on the index with event tracking but they still don't reflect on GA. The page source can be found at view-source:http://zookphotography.org/                                 Once again, thanks!